# R function, error

Tags: r, function

I have this function `f(n) = 5*f(n - 1) - n^2` where n>2. I know that `f(0) = 1`. 
I am trying to calculate the value of f(10) and have written this in R

```
myf <- function(n) 5*f(n - 1) - n^2
```

Now if I write `myf(10)` I get an error message:

> Error in myf(10) : could not find function "f"

I understand that R thinks that `f` is a second variable although there is only one (`n`). How should I change `myf` to let R know that there is only one variable and it should automatically calculate `f(n - 1)`?

Comment: Questions about how to code in R are off topic here. This will be on topic on [SO]. If you wait, we will migrate it there.

Comment: `f(n) = 5*f(n - 1) - ^2` seems to be missing something - the `n` I suppose. Looking up 'recursion' might help.

Comment: *"I understand that R thinks that f is a second variable..."* - No, R thinks `f` is a function because you are calling it like a function. Did you mean to use `myf(n - 1)`?

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for a recursive function where the function get called in the body should have the same name as the function itself as noticed by @nrussell:

```
f <- function(n) if(n == 0) 1 else 5*f(n - 1) - n^2
f(10)
# [1] 5188020
```

You can also use the `Recall` function within the definition of `f`, which makes sure that if `f` is renamed, the new function name will be called within:

```
f <- function(n) if(n == 0) 1 else 5 * Recall(n - 1) - n^2
```